# Write url citation in new line with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

How can I write all url citation in new line using `unsrt` style. But I don't want use `\par` in `*.bib` file (like `test1` bibdata).

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myRef.bib}
@misc{test,
title = {This is a test},
author = {Mirzakhani, Bahman},
howpublished = {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}},
}
@misc{test1,
title = {This is a test},
author = {Mirzakhani, Bahman},
howpublished = {\par\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\cite{test}
\cite{test1}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{myRef}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In my view, the core of the problem is that you use an ancient bibliography style -- `unsrt` -- which predates the creation of the World Wide Web and hence doesn't know what do with a field called `url`. You appear to have chosen to use -- mis-use, really, in my view -- the `howpublished` field for entries of type `@misc` in order to display suitable URL information. (Presumably, you've come up with further work-arounds for entries of type `@article`, `@book`, etc.) Precisely because the `howpublished` field may contain information other than URL strings, ... (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued from preceding comment) ... it is *not* advisable to edit the code in the `unsrt.bst` style file to force an automatic line break at the start of the `howpublished` field. The real solution lies in switching to a more modern bib style -- say, `unsrtnat` -- that's been programmed to know what do with the contents of `url` fields and which automatically insert line breaks at the start of the `url` field. Conversely, if you don't want to switch bib styles, you'll be stuck with inserting `\par` directives in suitable places.

Comment: @Mico, Thank you for your explanation. I will try to use more modern bib style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the core of the problem is that you are using an ancient bibliography style -- `unsrt` -- which predates the creation of the World Wide Web and hence doesn't know what do with a field called `url`. You appear to have chosen to use -- *mis-use*, in my view -- the `howpublished` field for entries of type `@misc` in order to display suitable URL information. Presumably, you've come up with further work-arounds for entries of type `@article`, `@book`, etc.

Precisely because the `howpublished` field may contain information other than URL strings, it is *not advisable* to edit the `unsrt.bst` style file to force an automatic line break at the start of the `howpublished` field.

The real solution lies in switching to a more modern bib style -- say, `unsrtnat` -- that's been programmed to know what do with the contents of `url` fields, and to edit the bib entries so that URL-related information is contained in the `url` fields (and nowhere else).

It's straightforward to modify the `unsrtnat` style to instruct it to insert a line break at the start of `url` fields. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of that file and name the copy, say, `unsrtnat-urlbreak.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `unsrtnat-urlbreak.bst` in a text editor -- the program you use to edit your .tex files will do fine -- and locate the function `format.url`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 285 and occupies all of six lines.
- In that function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { new.block "\par \url{" url * "}" * }
  ```

  i.e., replace `URL` with `\par`.
- Save the file in the directory that contains the main tex file.
- In the main tex file, change

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-urlbreak}
  ```
- Run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, and LaTeX once more -- to fully propagate all changes.

An MWE and its output:

[image]

Observe also that if the `year` field is non-empty, then information contained in the `howpublished` field will come *before* rather than after the `year` field if the `unsrtnat` and `unsrt` bib styles are employed. That's another reason for not using the `howpublished` field to store URL strings; for sure, it would be bad to generate a line break right before the URL string if the `year` field information gets separated from the remainder of the formatted bibliographic entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myRef.bib}
@misc{test1,
title   = {This is a test},
author  = {Mirzakhani, Bahman},
year    = 3001,
howpublished = {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}},
}
@misc{test2,
title   = {This is another test},
author  = {Mirzakhani, Bahman},
year    = 3002,
url     = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-urlbreak}
\usepackage{xurl} % for '\url' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{test1}, \cite{test2}

\raggedright
\bibliography{myRef}
\end{document}
```